# Is there a better way to do headings for (all) archives?

Tags: archives

I've been writing wordpress themes for years now and am kind of getting bored of copy-pasting the same bunch of code for archive titles.

Let's say I have 1 template for yearly and monthly archives, categories, tag archives, etc. I have a copypasta that spans like 40 lines and is basically a huge if/else thing which generates the relevant heading.

Is there something more sane/quick to build the heading text?

Comment: Could you please file an [edit] and show the code that you are currently using? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own template function which you reuse instead of copy&paste. Basically put something like this in your functions.php

```
function my_theme_archive_header(){
    echo "Custom header output";
}
```

Then you just put a call to this function in your template.

```
my_theme_archive_header();
```